# Session Id in php and jsp

Tags: java, php, jsp, servlets

1. I am  trying the session_id function in PHP and my understing is it's  unique for each user that used the website and session id is stored in webserver? Not sure whether the session is maintained in the apache tomcat webserver.
2. However, if i have a JSP page also in the same tomcat webserver  will i be able to access the session id created in php page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP Session ID is stored on the user's browser, in a cookie (or as a URL parameter in case it needs to fallback).

So yes, you'll be able to access it using Java. By default the cookie is called `PHPSESSID`

But the content of the session is not saved in the browser.

You can use the [session_save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) on PHP to setup a directory you can read using Java.